# Visual Basic in Excel Refusing to Allow me to Assign Application.ActiveSheet to a variable

Tags: vba

This is the entirety of the VBA and I can't figure out it's failure.

```
Sub TestActiveSheet()
    Dim ws_tmp As Worksheet
    Dim ws_active As Worksheet
    
    ws_active = Application.ActiveSheet
    'Debug.Print ws_active.Name
End Sub
```

"Object variable or With block variable not set" is the error, but both of the variables are set. How is this possibly a problem? Is this a widely regarded bug in the software?

Comment: "but both of the variables are set...". Well they aren't, you're missing a `Set`.

Comment: Thanks, I don't get why the community has to confuse me by steering me further down an unrelated rabbit hole. Feels very unwelcoming these days. But yes, the keyword "set" was my issue!

Comment: Very unclear how you're getting confused here, or where the unrelated rabbit hole is. That said, there are many many questions on SO dealing with this error. A simple search or read of the docs might be more beneficial than posting a question.